# How do I attack Skulltulas sitting on their webs?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I can't seem to figure out how to attack the Skulltulas who are sitting on their webs. I tried various different directions of sword slashes with no effect (on the enemy - it usually ended with me losing hearts as they bounced and hit me).

What do I do to kill them? At some point, I would really like to get past the first dungeon! I am looking for the exact type of sword slash or weapon I need to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Skulltulas** are less dangerous when they are on the ground.  They are very easy to dispatch of as it only really takes two hits to kill them, an upward slash to knock them onto their backs and a final **Fatal Blow** to kill them.  If you ever get the chance to do so, cut them off their webs to kill them, it's very easy to accidentally get hit when you attack them and rebound.

They (AFAIK) only come in two forms, hanging on a web string and will go down to your level when you get close or on a full web usually facing you.

When on a string, you could use your **Beetle** on the string to cut them down.  Otherwise if you don't have it (or don't want to pull it out and rather fight them), you need to find a way to turn them so you can attack their weak spot, their bellies.  To do that, do one horizontal slash (in either direction) so they are knocked to the side and spin around.  After they spin (you may need to wait a bit), they should be turned around so their bellies are facing you.  When that happens, do straight stabs forward to attack and kill them.  Just be careful of the rebounds when they swing.

When on the webs, you have a couple of options.  It should be easier to get past them as they usually don't move.

If they're on a web but are sitting at ground level, try to get behind them if possible so you could forward stab them in their bellies.  If not, you'll have to cut them down so you can fight them on the ground.  Just cut at their webs and they'll eventually get off to fight.

If they're on a web but not at ground level, you can actually just go though the web with relative ease.  Run toward the web and at the last second, roll (shake the nunchuk).  You should be able to perform the roll almost completely through.  You'll get caught in the web for a second but will break free almost immediately.  At this point you could go on or turn around and finish it off using the strategies when they're at ground level.

Comment: Took me forever to figure out the `upward slash` on my own.

Answer (score 7):

Skulltulas will appear in several different ways. Some just drop down the ceiling, others are hanging from a string, while some have full blown spider webs created to block your path. Link can knock down skulltulas by breaking the string or spider web utilizing the beetle.

Once a skulltula is on the ground, Link can then use an upward slash to knock the Skulltula on its back, revealing its weak spot. Link can then use a fatal blow to kill it in one hit.

If you are before the beetle stage, you can't get past these webbed Skulltulas, so hit the two vines along the far wall and swing across. Kill the Skulltula that is now facing its back towards you, stand on the bridge and look left - there's a switch in a small alcove in the wall, hit it. This will further raise the water level.

Comment: I don't have the beetle. What else can I do?